# Open Word Document and Bring to Front

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Below is a working code snippet that opens a Microsoft Word document, and goes to a specific index from the Table of Contents. `filePath` is a filepath, and `strTopic` is a value that links to the Table of Contents in the Word document.

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True

Set docWord = objWord.Documents.Open(fileName:=strPath, ReadOnly:=True)

docWord.Bookmarks(strTopic).Range.Select
```

I need to bring the Word document to the foreground.

Is there a `toFront()` type "function" in VBA?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using APIS. I am using two APIs [SetForegroundWindow](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/SetForegroundWindow.shtml) and [FindWindow](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/FindWindow.shtml)

```
Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) _
As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias _
"FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) _
As Long

Sub Sample()
    Dim objWord As Object, docWord As Object
    Dim strPath As String, FileName As String
    Dim hwnd As Long

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True

    '~~> Change this to the relevant Filename and path
    strPath = "C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\Desktop\Sample.docx"
    '~~> Put the acutal file name here without the extension
    FileName = "Sample"

    Set docWord = objWord.Documents.Open(FileName:=strPath, ReadOnly:=True)

    hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, FileName & " [Read-Only] - Microsoft Word")

    If hwnd > 0 Then
      SetForegroundWindow (hwnd)
    End If
End Sub
```

**NOTE**: If you are sure that there is no other Word Application open other than what you opened then you can use this as well :)

```
Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias _
"FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Sub Sample()
    Dim objWord As Object, docWord As Object
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim hwnd As Long

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True

    '~~> Change this to the relevant Filename and path
    strPath = "C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\Desktop\Sample.docx"

    Set docWord = objWord.Documents.Open(FileName:=strPath, ReadOnly:=True)

    hwnd = FindWindow("OpusApp", vbNullString)
    If hwnd > 0 Then
      SetForegroundWindow (hwnd)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting a "remote server does not exist" error running the above (there may be instances of word open, so I'm using the first one). This line `Set docWord = objWord.Documents.Open(FileName:=strPath, ReadOnly:=True)` seems to be the "issue". I say "issue" as it is probably me missing something obvious!

Comment: What is the value of `strPath`?

Comment: Deleted as a bit sensitive, but basically S: (network drive) \blah.dox

Comment: Is that network drive accessible? :) Try the above code with a sample file on a local drive

Comment: BTW both the above codes are tried and tested on a local file.

Comment: It works locally, brilliant, many thanks indeed. The network issue I can ask about here, and work with. Thanks again!

Comment: kool I always prefer the APIs way because `.Activate` is not a reliable approach as `objWord.Activate` will not work as expected if multiple files are opened in the same instance `objWord` but in different windows.

Comment: This answer works great! It could be even simpler: you can use the answer from @John0987 , getting the exact hwnd of your document with the .ActiveWindow.hWnd method, without having to search the window title with the FindWindow API call.

Answer (score 4):

How about,

```
docWord.Activate
```

This should bring the file that has been "Set" for the docWord object to foreground.

EDIT: Tested this on Access, quiet unreliable on Excel. Using an API is the best way to go if there are multiple instances of the Word application running.

Comment: Hi, thanks a million. Just one slight blip, the window opens NON maximised every time I run this. Which seems odd with "wdWinwodStateMaximize"  Is there something obvious here. The window is brought to the fore so that's brilliant (and much appreciated). Just want to clarify if I'm missing anything before accepting your answer!

Comment: Leave that LOC. It is not really required, I was just playing with them both. (I will edit the reply). Feel free to mark this as answer, so other can benefit from this.

Comment: + 1 :) Simplest would have been `objWord.Activate` ?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, It would have indeed been more simple ;)

Comment: True. However a word of caution. `.Activate` is not a reliable approach as `objWord.Activate` will not work as expected if multiple files are opened in the same instance `objWord` but in different windows. ;)

Comment: Even if the Object has been declare/set to a particular file? If Word.Application.Activate is used, then there is a possibility for the Activate method to not trigger the right file. If an instance of the file has been set to the docWord Object, then Object.Activate should only activate the instance of the Object, right? Maybe I could be wrong. I will do a simple test and find out ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, had a quick play around. Maybe I am doing it wrong, but I can get the right file brought in fore ground if I use docWord.Activate, but if I used Word.Application.Activate then I get the per-opened file popping up instead. Which is what I based my theory for an answer. Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Strange. because I can't get that to happen :) The code that i am using is http://wikisend.com/download/399800/Sample Code.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59504/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-paulfrancis).

Answer (score 4):

Once you've opened a document (or added one) you can get a Hwnd to pass to the SetForegroundWindow API function from the ActiveWindow object (e.g. obWord.ActivieWindow.Hwnd). That way you don't need to search for the correct Word instance to bring to front.

Comment: This works perfectly! It would be useful to merge this into the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work every time. Word running or not, multiple docs open or not.

```
OpenAlready:

On Error GoTo 0
With wrdApp
    .Selection.Goto What:=1, Which:=2, Name:=PageNumber
    .Visible = True
    .Activate '<---seems to work well. regardless of number of Word docs open OR not open.
End With
Set wrdDoc = Nothing
Set wrdApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm quite new here, and in doing a ~30 min research on this specific case, I think I could bring something to the table here...

I found in this link: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?27589-bringing-Word-in-fornt-of-Excel this line of code:
Application.ActivateMicrosoftApp xlMicrosoftWord
It will force Word in front of everything, BUT if there is something opened it will create a new document, so what I found is that, if you want to open something and then bring it to front you use this sintax:

[...]

```
Application.ActivateMicrosoftApp xlMicrosoftWord
Word.Documents.Open(MyDocument)
```

[...]

Once in vba debugging the code will always be in front, but when using the code with the excel vba userform it works great! I can see the word changing the words on the fly!!!!

Comment: This works in part but also sometimes seems to create a new document instead of activating the one that's already open.

Answer (score 0):

Can also use AppActivate "Microsoft Word"

visit Microsoft help :[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278643(v=office.15).aspx)

Using AppActivate needs the exact title of the window you want focused. E.g. for a word 2013 template opened as an "add", you would have to use AppActivate "Document1 - Word"

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. What if there are multiple instances of MS Word opened?

Answer (score 0):

I just use;

```
FileAndPath = "C:\temp\Mydocument.docx"
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (FileAndPath)
```

It even works if the file is already open.

Answer (score 0):

Since ".Activate" is comented various times but at least for me calling it from excel to bring to fornt a word doc.
I have to do a work around minimizing and maximazing the window.
This works well for me until now:

```
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wdApp.Visible = True
wdApp.ScreenUpdating = True
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & stWordDocument) 'update your path
wdDoc.Activate
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow _
.WindowState = wdWindowStateMinimize
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow _
.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
```

Answer (score -2):

found!

```
ActiveDocument.Activate 'might not be necessary
ActiveDocument.Windows.Application.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
```

works flawlessly. I already had an "activedocument" I was working on.

http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=173871