# How to find title of window of programmatically opened word document .net

Tags: .net, ms-word, window, office-interop

My applications opens up multiple documents in their own application instance and I need to find a way to store each of their window names such I can set them to the foreground using [Open Word Document and Bring to Front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362563/open-word-document-and-bring-to-front).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines would work to get the caption in the Word document's title bar. Note that you'll want to check how the version(s) of Word you're targeting present this information. As I recall, it's been fairly consistent in recent years, but twenty or so years ago it was different. So better to be sure before you release production code...

```
objDocument.ActiveWindow.caption + " - " + objDocument.Parent.Caption
```

Every document window will have its own caption - Word can display the same document in multiple windows, each caption will be different. You don't need to use `ActiveWindow`, you could also use `Windows[index]`, for example `Windows[1]` to get the first document window if there is more than one. I doubt this will have an effect on your purpose, but "good to know". The Caption is usually the document .Name.

The document's Parent is the Word application; its Caption gives you the caption for the application ("Microsoft Word", which appears on the right.

Comment: not my downvote, so I can only guess. But I suspect that some people reading it felt you hadn't done enough research or something. Sometimes, people without a lot of in-depth knowledge on a topic have trouble with short problem descriptions...