# EXCEL - Commandbutton click to open document IN FRONT

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm using the following code to open a document from a Userform. It works fine, the document opens, however it opens in the background and the user may not know the file has opened unless they see the Word icon blinking on their taskbar. How can I get this code to make sure the document opens in front of the Excel document they're using? Any help would be greatly appreciated, have a great day!

```
Private Sub SPECDOC_Click()
On Error Resume Next
Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
appWD.Visible = True
appWD.Documents.Open FileName:="File Location"
End Sub
```

Comment: Wherever you have `UserForm1.Show` (assuming the name), try putting `UserForm1.Show vbModeless`. Also, [check out this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362563/open-word-document-and-bring-to-front) which seems very very similar to what you're tying to do. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work, hopefully it helps someone else in the future:

```
Private Sub SPECDOC_Click()
On Error Resume Next
Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
appWD.Visible = True
appWD.Activate
appWD.Documents.Open FileName:="File Location"
End Sub
```