# Open Word Document in Excel and Bring to Front in Windows 10 environment

Tags: windows, vba, excel, ms-word

I want to open word document in Excel and bring the word document to front.

I have tried the solution in: [Open Word Document and Bring to Front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362563/open-word-document-and-bring-to-front)

However, this solution only works in Windows 8 and Windows 2012 server environment.

The end result is that I would like to have a solution that also works in Windows 10 environment.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Which office are you using?

Comment: I use office 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following work for you?

```
Sub openword()

Dim Wapp As Object
Dim Wdoc As Object

Set Wapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
With Wapp
   .Visible = True
   Set Wdoc = .documents.Open("path")
   .Activate
End With



End Sub
```