# batch running in the background

Tags: powershell, batch-file, workload

I am working with CA workload automation, I tell it to run a batch file or a ps file and it does but the things I tell it to run, it runs them in the background, is there a  way to force a batch file to run in the foreground o visually?

EDIT

```
start /wait /d"C:\Turing\App\" TuringExpo.exe "456555384" "Test"
```

```
start /wait /d"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\" winword.exe
```

Comment: Are we supposed to help you to fix code you haven't posted? That's the purpose of this site, after all, _you provide a replicable issue, by supplying the code and necessary environment in order for us to reproduce your issue, and we can then provide a specific focused solution_.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't post anything because it's a one line command in cmd or powershell and I just wanted to know if there's a command to force to run it visually  but I edited my question, thank you for the help

Comment: To start with, neither of those lines use Powershell syntax!

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\winword.exe` see `start /?` as it documents executing a program with and without (the normal way) `start`. Esp the part GUI apps in a batch file wait (because NT4 did).

Comment: @Compo and what about batch? I also said batch file, do you want the powershell?

Comment: @Mark I'm sorry I didn't understand

Comment: `winword` alone, _or `winword.exe`, if `%PATHEXT%` has had `.EXE` removed_, will usually be sufficient, as Microsoft adds the necessary configuration, to prevent you having to provide its full path.

Answer (score 0):

As for this ...

> 'batch running in the background'
>
> is there a way to force a batch file to run in the foreground o
>   visually?

... PowerShell when you call and external file, ie., .exe or .bat, the are defined ways to call these and address your use case. This is well documented all over the web. As noted, those commands are not PowerShell, they are just batch stuff in a PowerShell script or I am going to assume these are what is in your batch file.

All that being said, the process of calling an external file is defined.

No real need to do this as a batch file. Just call this directly in a PowerShell script.

See also details the following---

[PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.asp)

```
# Example(s):
& 'C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe' "c:\videos\my home video.avi"  /fullscreen

<#
Things can get tricky when an external command has a lot of parameters or there 
are spaces in the arguments or paths!
With spaces, you have to nest Quotation marks and the result it is not always 
clear!
In this case, it is better to separate everything like so:
#>

$CMD =  'SuperApp.exe'
$arg1 =  'filename1'
$arg2 =  '-someswitch'
$arg3 =  'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt'
$arg4 =  '-yetanotherswitch'
& $CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4

# or something like this:
$AllArgs =  @('filename1',  '-someswitch', 'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt', '-yetanotherswitch')
& 'SuperApp.exe' $AllArgs


<#
** This method should no longer be used with V3
Why: Bypasses PowerShell and runs the command from a cmd shell. Often times used
with a DIR which runs faster in the cmd shell than in PowerShell (NOTE: This was
an issue with PowerShell v2 and its use of .Net 2.0, this is not an issue with 
V3).

Details: Opens a CMD prompt from within PowerShell and then executes 
the command and returns the text of that command. The /c tells CMD that 
it should terminate after the command has completed. There is little to 
no reason to use this with V3.
#>

# Example:
<#
runs DIR from a cmd shell, DIR in PowerShell is an alias to GCI. This will 
return the directory listing as a string but returns much faster than a GCI
#>

cmd /c dir c:\windows
```

See also

> [Execution of external commands in PowerShell done right](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/execution-of-external-commands-in-powershell-done-right)
>
> [PowerShell and external commands done right](http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right)
>   'https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/execution-of-external-commands-in-powershell-done-right'
>
> [Top 5 tips for running external commands in Powershell](https://powershelleverydayfaq.blogspot.com/2012/04/top-5-tips-for-running-external.html)
>
> [PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)
>
> [Solve Problems with External Command Lines in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/solve-problems-with-external-command-lines-in-)
>
> [Using Windows PowerShell to run old command-line tools (and their
>   weirdest parameters)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters)
>
> [Quoating specifics](https://trevorsullivan.net/2016/07/20/powershell-quoting)
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules

So, this ...

```
start /wait /d"C:\Turing\App\" TuringExpo.exe "456555384" "Test"
start /wait /d"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\" winword.exe
```

... could become something link this, just using PowerShell, no batch file involved:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Turing\App\TuringExpo.exe' -ArgumentList '456555384', 'Test' -Wait
Start-Process -FilePath winword -Wait
```

Comment: thank you @postanote I have also tried that and it does execute the job but, it does it in the background, I open task manager and in the Details tab I see the app running but I don't see it visually and I don't know why is that

Comment: Are you talking Word (which that start will fire off Word in interactive mode) or this TuringExpo.exe (which I've no idea what that is of course). Also, you don't say whether you are trying to do this locally or on a remote host. You cannot see interactive apps on a remote host. Is this the stuff you are trying to do? https://community.broadcom.com/enterprisesoftware/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=aa995401-902a-45d2-90cd-8842667a3b7f&CommunityKey=2e1b01c9-f310-4635-829f-aead2f6587c4&tab=digestviewer

Comment: yes that's what I am trying to do, and I am trying with local and remote and both do it in the background

Answer (score 0):

This can be more simple...

1) Pay attention to @compo comments, remove path to **`winword.exe`**

```
start /wait /d"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\" winword.exe
```

2) For works with **`TuringExpo.exe`**, you need use the correct name/windows, maybe only name.exe don't gona works.

3) The 3 last lines in code vbs is adapted from this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25362770/8177207)** /by **[@Siddharth Rout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140579/siddharth-rout)**

---

```cmd
@echo off 

(
echo/ Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
echo/ WScript.Sleep 999
echo/ objShell.AppActivate "TuringExpo"
echo/ WScript.Sleep 999
echo/ Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application"^)
echo/ objWord.Visible = True
echo/ SetForegroundWindow ("objWord"^)
) >"%temp%\Show_Active_TMP.vbs"

start "" /b /d "C:\Turing\App\" "TuringExpo.exe" "456555384" "Test" 
start "" /b /d "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\" "winword.exe"

"%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe" 2 & "%windir%\System32\CScript.exe" "%temp%\Show_Active_TMP.vbs" //nologo 
del /q /f "%temp%\Show_Active_TMP.vbs"  & rem./ Next line you may add many commands... or && goto :eof
```